# Synonymize /unicode with /utf-8

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Unicode isn't a synonym of UTF-8, but it is a superset. Since UTF-8 is the de facto standard representation of Unicode in the unix world, most questions about Unicode on this site involve UTF-8. While some questions are specifically about UTF-8 and others are about in Unicode in general, we don't seem to be following any rule as to which questions are tagged [unicode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) and which ones are tagged [utf-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) (beyond perhaps the rare question about other representations not being tagged [utf-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)).

I don't see any point in having two separate tags. This only makes it harder to find Unicode-related questions since there are two tags to search. Therefore, I propose to make [utf-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) a synonym of [unicode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode). ([unicode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) has to be the main tag since it's more general.)

I can't propose the synonym through the tag interface because “Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[utf-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) and [utf8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf8) both point to [unicode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) now and are merged